# frameworkを消去したらエラーがでてしまった

Tags: swift, realm, xcode7

Xcodeのバージョンをあげたらエラーが出てしまいました。

> /Users/rei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-cjirudbxomehmmeehfnapyosogkz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory

以前入れていたframeworkを消去したのですが、うまく消去できていないようです。
ネットをみてデベロッパーも消去してみたのですが、未だにエラーが出ています・・・
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セットアップ手順のうち、最後の「Run Script Phase」に追加したスクリプトが残ったままになっているのが原因だと思います。

> 5. iOS、またはwatchOSのプロジェクトで利用する場合は、アプリケーションのターゲットの“Build Phases”タブで新しく“Run Script Phase”を追加し、以下のスクリプトをそのままコピー＆ペーストしてください。 bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh" この手順はアプリケーションを申請する際のiTunes Connectの不具合を回避するために必要です。

https://realm.io/jp/docs/objc/latest/#section-2

プロジェクト設定の「Build Phases」（下記の画面）を確認して、「Run Script」セクションが残っていたら、右の「x」ボタンで削除して、それから再ビルドしてみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: やってみたところ，無事エラーが消えました．他の部分は残ってないか見ていたのですが，そこは一切見ていなかったので，本当に助かりました．ありがとうございます．

Comment: @Rei 解決した場合は、回答を「承認」してください。そうしないと、いつまでもこの質問が未解決の状態で定期的に上がってくることになります。

Comment: わざわざすみません。ありがとうございます。承認しました。